# Akamai CDN query

Tags: web, hosting, cdn, kentico, akamai

I need confirmation regarding the CDN approach that I am going to implement for a *Content management website*

I have following areas into consideration

1. Implementing CDN for Assets like images,fonts,vedios, hopefully i need to replace asset url links with cdn links.
2. CDN implementation for conents of the webpage other than assets like texts and paragraph
3. CDN implementation for full website , the full website need to be stored in CDN servers.

Also , please let me know when a change in the content through CMS to the website,ideally it should effect CDN websites also,do the contents replaces immediatly after the change of contents in website. Or it takes ages/days to replace the contents in akamai servers?

Is there any more areas I need to consider the areas mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you need basically. How soon the content should reflect in the live website, do you want to host the website at your origin server and cache static content at CDN and how long, or do you want to host the website within CDN etc. Akamai can do all of that.